# VBA to update sharepoint list inside a folder

Tags: vba, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to update a sharepoint list inside a folder. The structure us as below

NewGLJE Log_List_New : 2018 : 12 Dec 18

With the below code I am able to add a new item to the main folder which is NewGLJE Log_List_New however want to update in the 12 Dec 18 folder. the code is below

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddNew_SP()
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mySQL As String

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [NewGLJE Log_List_New];"


With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=http://staging.gl.firstam.net/sites/IFSC/GL/;LIST={71D20BD2-393D-4055-AFC7-476BB8776DE3};"
    .Open
End With

rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rst.AddNew
    rst.Fields("JE/Batch Name") = "JE1234Test"
    rst.Fields("Division") = "DBS"
    rst.Fields("Description") = "TEST"
    rst.Fields("Control Total") = "10000"
rst.Update

If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

I tried editing the sql statement to include the sub folders, however that gives a syntax error.

Can anyone please help me how to get to updating the list in the sub folders.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of ADO, would using a ListObject be suited for your goal? You can check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/930006/a-sharepoint-list-is-converted-to-a-table-and-synchronization-of-the-s) to see.

Comment: Hello, apologies i missed to mention that I am trying this in Outlook. So as a mail comes it gets logged in to sharepoint to the respective year and month. I already have a event handler code which activates when the mail arives and Get folder function code to find the folder ready. Is there a way in the My Sql  statement I can select the sub folder and not the main one. Thanks

Comment: Hello. Also wanted to know how to update for people picker as its giving the error type mismatch. Appreciate your help